# jsf selectOneMenu value does not change

Tags: jsf, triggers

I have a selectOneMenu that have the correct values (a list of string) however when I select a value it does not trigger the setSelectedValue from the bean.

```
<h:selectOneMenu layout="lineDirection" id="myMenu" value="#{dwrBean.selectedValue}"> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.values}"/> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Bean:

```
private String selectedValue = "";
private List<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();

...

public String getSelectedValue() {
    return this.selectedValue;
}

public void setSelectedValue(String selectedValue) {
    LOGGER.debug("Try to set selected value" + selectedValue);
    if (!selectedValue.isEmpty()){
        this.selectedValue = selectedValue ;
    }
}
```

There is nothing in the logs.

I've tried to add a listener:

```
<h:selectOneMenu layout="lineDirection" id="myMenu" value="#{dwrBean.selectedValue}" valueChangeListener="#{dwrBean.statusChanged}" > 
    <f:selectItems value="#{dwrBean.values}"/> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Here the statusChanged is triggered but the newValue is null, the oldValue is correct, but it is always the same.

```
public void statusChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    LOGGER.debug("new" + event.getNewValue());
    LOGGER.debug("old" + event.getOldValue());

    if (event.getNewValue() != null && 
            !((String) event.getNewValue()).isEmpty()) {

            LOGGER.debug("OK");
        }
}
```

I really don't understand.

Actually the selectOneMenu is within a popup.

I've moved the selectOneMenu outside of the popup and it works. Do I have to change the scope of the Bean ?

Non-working configuration:

```
<h:form>
     <rich:popupPanel>
          <h:selectOneMenu>
               ...
          </h:selectOneMenu>
     <rich:popupPanel>
<h:form>
```

Working configuration:

```
<h:form>
          <h:selectOneMenu>
               ...
          </h:selectOneMenu>
     <rich:popupPanel>

     <rich:popupPanel>
<h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

below method invoke when you subbmit form

```
public void setSelectedValue(String selectedValue) {
    LOGGER.debug("Try to set selected value" + selectedValue);
    if (!selectedValue.isEmpty()){
        this.selectedValue = selectedValue ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want the selectedValue to be set when another element is selected in the selectOneMenu, not when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to do a partial form submission when the value changes. The valueChangeListener is a hook that provides your code with notification when the value has changed and the form has been submitted.

The code below will register an AJAX event for the onchange event for selectOneMenu. The value changes it will then execute the menu (submit the value to the bean).

```
<h:selectOneMenu layout="lineDirection" id="myMenu" value="#{dwrBean.selectedValue}"> 
   <f:selectItems value="#{dwrBean.values}"/> 
   <f:ajax/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```